# Need help to add symbols automatically to a long list of cell values

Tags: microsoft-excel, macros

I have a long row of SYMBOLS. Example:
AAA
BBB
CCC
..
..
Etc.

I need to add " " around the symbols and I need to ad a comma at the end of the symbol. My row should look like this:
"AAA",
"BBB",
"CCC",
...
"ZZZ",

Comment: Why do you need it in this particular format?  CSV files wouldn't need the quotes around each string.

Comment: Is it a single cell with a long string of text, or something else?

Comment: the formula `=Substitute()` might work

Answer (score 0):

1. Use **Replace** function.

[image]

**Result:**
[image]

2. Use formula **=CHAR(34)&A1&CHAR(34)** in an empty cell.
   [image]